# AAC stream has errors, but I can't use ffmpeg to show me errors

Tags: ffmpeg

I saw some results here on stack related to this issue, but I just can't make it to work for my life. What is wrong with this command? How was I supposed to run it?

```
ffmpeg -err_detect explode http://ohnewerbung.ice.infomaniak.ch/radiobasilisk-64-0.aac
```

This gives the error: `Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

I'm running ffmpeg on a mac if it makes any difference. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ffmpeg app is designed as a transcoder, so it expects an input and some target output details.

Firstly, an input has to be fed as an argument to `-i`. Then, some output has to be specified. Since you wish to analyze the input, the null muxer is best suited for that. No output will actually be written.

```
ffmpeg -err_detect explode -i http://ohnewerbung.ice.infomaniak.ch/radiobasilisk-64-0.aac -f null -
```